# How does the class weight parameter work in sklearn RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

The effect of the class weights parameter internally in the algorithm

Comment: [Line 160](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L160) from the source code may help.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `RandomForestClassifier`,  impurity (Gini or Entropy) is used to measure how mixed the groups of samples are given a split within your tree. This calculation can be biased as it depends on the distribution of your `y` variable.

If your `y` distribution is unbalanced, the impurity measurements will be biased as well. Therefore, to counter that effect, you can use the `class_weight` parameter to adjust those measurements so that the majority class is not favored.